# Add CMS Block to product view and category page

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block

What is the best way of adding a CMS Block under the breadcrumb on a product listing page and a different one on a product view page.

Magento 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

Create your CMS Block in 'Static Blocks' section, then go to 'Widgets' under CMS and add new Widget Instance from your static block, and put it anywhere you want from 'Layout Updates' section.

Comment: Funny thing is I can't make a new widget because the "Widget Instance
Frontend Properties" are completely blank. Any ideas?

Comment: Well it seems a different problem, I suggest you add a new question about this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Call static block using below code to your catalog/product/view.phtml and catalog/product/list.phtml according to your requirement. Change the block_identifier with your identifier.

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml(); ?>
```